# Communication with the service provider failed: No peer certificate in Twitter

Tags: android, service-provider

I integrated the twitter API in my application for posting a message. It is generating an exception like this:

```
oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: No peer certificate
```

@Pawan's comment of updating the device time to current time solved the issue.

Comment: @Harry:Please update your device time to current time.Hope it will work for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: No peer certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992740/android-oauth-signpost-exception-oauthcommunicationexception-communication-wit)

Answer (score 0):

Probably is a ssl certificate issue, no? Take a look [Android SSL HttpGet (No peer certificate) error OR (Connection closed by peer) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16719959/android-ssl-httpget-no-peer-certificate-error-or-connection-closed-by-peer-e)

:)