# Android SSL HttpGet (No peer certificate) error OR (Connection closed by peer) error

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, httpclient

I am trying to do a simple HttpGet to read a webpage. I have this working on iOS and working on Android over http, but not https.

The url is an internal network IP and custom port, so I can read with http like this using a path of `http://ipaddress:port/MyPage.html`

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
                    HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            // Try connection
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(params[0].path);
            get.addHeader("Authorization",
                    "Basic "
                            + Base64.encodeBytes(new String(params[0].username + ":" + params[0].password)
                                    .getBytes()));
        response = httpclient.execute(get);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
            out.close();
            responseString = out.toString();
        } else {
            // Closes the connection.
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ClientProtocolException");
        this.e = e;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException");
        this.e = e;
    }
    return responseString;
```

When I try using https, I get the `No peer certificate` error. So I have tried using this code:
`HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);`

```
private HttpClient createHttpClient() {
        try {
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);

            SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET);
            HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);

            SchemeRegistry schReg = new SchemeRegistry();
            schReg.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
            schReg.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 8080));
            ClientConnectionManager conMgr = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schReg);

            return new DefaultHttpClient(conMgr, params);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new DefaultHttpClient();
        }
    }
```

but this gives me a `Connection closed by peer` error.

What am I doing wrong? I can safely ignore the certificate, as it's an internal network with self signed cert, however I have no control over the vert and users of my app may have different certs, so I really need to auto accept or bypass it.

Thanks

EDIT ------------------------------

After trying My-Name-Is answer below:
I've created a CustomX509TrustManager class as suggested, then create a custom HttpClient using it like this:

```
private HttpClient sslClient(HttpClient client) {
        try {
            CustomX509TrustManager tm = new CustomX509TrustManager();
            SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
            SSLSocketFactory ssf = new MySSLSocketFactory(ctx);
            ssf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
            ClientConnectionManager ccm = client.getConnectionManager();
            SchemeRegistry sr = ccm.getSchemeRegistry();
            sr.register(new Scheme("https", ssf, 8080));
            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, client.getParams());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And finally use this HttpClient like this:

```
private class httpGETTask extends AsyncTask<GetParams, Void, String> {
private Exception e = null;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(GetParams... params) {
    // Set connection parameters
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    int timeoutConnection = 15000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
    int timeoutSocket = 15000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

    Log.v(TAG, params[0].path);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
    httpclient = sslClient(httpclient);

    HttpResponse response;
    String responseString = null;
    try {
        // Try connection
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(params[0].path);
        get.addHeader("Authorization",
                "Basic "
                        + Base64.encodeBytes(new String(params[0].username + ":" + params[0].password)
                                .getBytes()));

        response = httpclient.execute(get);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
            out.close();
            responseString = out.toString();
        } else {
            // Closes the connection.
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ClientProtocolException");
        this.e = e;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException");
        this.e = e;
    }
    return responseString;
```

The logged path is in the format `https://ipaddress:8080/Page.html`
But I get a `Connection closed By Peer` error:

> 05-24 08:20:32.500: E/ConnectionHelper(1129): IOException 05-24
>   08:20:32.550: E/ConnectionHelper(1129): Exception loading contents
>   05-24 08:20:32.550: E/ConnectionHelper(1129):
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer 05-24
>   08:20:32.550: E/ConnectionHelper(1129):   at
>   org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native
>   Method) 05-24 08:20:32.550: E/ConnectionHelper(1129):     at
>   org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:410)
>   05-24 08:20:32.550: E/ConnectionHelper(1129):     at
>   org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:643)
>   05-24 08:20:32.550: E/ConnectionHelper(1129):     at
>   org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:614)
>   05-24 08:20:32.550: E/ConnectionHelper(1129):     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.(SocketInputBuffer.java:70)
>   05-24 08:20:32.550: E/ConnectionHelper(1129):     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.createSessionInputBuffer(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:83)
>   05-24 08:20:32.550: E/ConnectionHelper(1129):     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.createSessionInputBuffer(DefaultClientConnection.java:170)
>   05-24 08:20:32.550: E/ConnectionHelper(1129):     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.bind(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:106)
>   05-24 08:20:32.550: E/ConnectionHelper(1129):     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.openCompleted(DefaultClientConnection.java:129)
>   05-24 08:20:32.550: E/ConnectionHelper(1129):     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:172)
>   05-24 08:20:32.550: E/ConnectionHelper(1129):     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
>   05-24 08:20:32.550: E/ConnectionHelper(1129):     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
>   05-24 08:20:32.550: E/ConnectionHelper(1129):     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
>   05-24 08:20:32.550: E/ConnectionHelper(1129):     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>   05-24 08:20:32.550: E/ConnectionHelper(1129):     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>   05-24 08:20:32.550: E/ConnectionHelper(1129):     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
>   05-24 08:20:32.550: E/ConnectionHelper(1129):     at
>   com.d_apps.my_app.connection_helpers.ConnectionHelper$httpGETTask.doInBackground(ConnectionHelper.java:114)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The following source should fix your problem.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.Header
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText text;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        connect();
    }

    private void connect(){
        try {
            DataLoader dl = new DataLoader();
            String url = "https://IpAddress";
            HttpResponse response = dl.secureLoadData(url); 

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("HEADERS:\n\n");

            Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
            for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
                Header h = headers[i];
                sb.append(h.getName()).append(":\t").append(h.getValue()).append("\n");
            }

            InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
            StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine())
                out.append(line);
            br.close();

            sb.append("\n\nCONTENT:\n\n").append(out.toString()); 

            Log.i("response", sb.toString());
            text.setText(sb.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}


import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import java.io.InputStream;
public class MeaApplication extends Application {

    private static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MeaApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MeaApplication.context;
    }

    public static InputStream loadCertAsInputStream() {
        return MeaApplication.context.getResources().openRawResource(
                R.raw.meacert);
    }

}


import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
/**
 * Taken from: http://janis.peisenieks.lv/en/76/english-making-an-ssl-connection-via-android/
 *
 */
public class CustomSSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    public CustomSSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException,
            KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);

        TrustManager tm = new CustomX509TrustManager();

        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
    }

    public CustomSSLSocketFactory(SSLContext context)
            throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(null);
        sslContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port,
            boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port,
                autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }
}


import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
public class CustomX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
            throws CertificateException {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs,
            String authType) throws CertificateException {

        // Here you can verify the servers certificate. (e.g. against one which is stored on mobile device)

        // InputStream inStream = null;
        // try {
        // inStream = MeaApplication.loadCertAsInputStream();
        // CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        // X509Certificate ca = (X509Certificate)
        // cf.generateCertificate(inStream);
        // inStream.close();
        //
        // for (X509Certificate cert : certs) {
        // // Verifing by public key
        // cert.verify(ca.getPublicKey());
        // }
        // } catch (Exception e) {
        // throw new IllegalArgumentException("Untrusted Certificate!");
        // } finally {
        // try {
        // inStream.close();
        // } catch (IOException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        // }
        // }
    }

    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }

}


import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
public class DataLoader {

    public HttpResponse secureLoadData(String url)
            throws ClientProtocolException, IOException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException,
            URISyntaxException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new CustomX509TrustManager() },
                new SecureRandom());

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        SSLSocketFactory ssf = new CustomSSLSocketFactory(ctx);
        ssf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        ClientConnectionManager ccm = client.getConnectionManager();
        SchemeRegistry sr = ccm.getSchemeRegistry();
        sr.register(new Scheme("https", ssf, 443));
        DefaultHttpClient sslClient = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm,
                client.getParams());

        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(new URI(url));
        HttpResponse response = sslClient.execute(get);

        return response;
    }

}
```

Comment: @benoffi7 Sure. At the moment I do not have the source code at hand. However, I'll add the imports tonight.

Comment: @benoffi7 Adding imports done :) I didn't compiled the project again, since I extracted the major parts from a more advanced project, some time ago. Unfortunately I couldn't find this modified project, so if there is any import missing, please let me it know.

Comment: After spending more than a day trying everything, finally this code worked for me. Only change I made was to modify it a little bit to use with my POST since i am not using GET for SSL. The other difference I have is that I don't have a class which extends Application, and I don't load any certificate locally. But still, it works fine. I am wondering by not loading my certificate locally, am I opening myself to any vulnerabilities, or I am still good? Or am I basically bypassing authentication without knowing it? I am not an expert in SSLs but it seems to be working smoothly without any error.

Comment: @zeeshan `I don't load any certificate locally [..] am I opening myself to any vulnerabilities` No, you don't introduce any vulnerabilities. This just allows you to additionlly verify the received certificat within your mobile application. `cert.verify(ca.getPublicKey());` I added this piece of source only to show one possibility of how to implement the `checkServerTrusted` method. For most applications it isn't necessary to do this check.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for this clarification. If my app will become famous (LifeLog24), I'll look into adding this additional check too :)

Comment: As far as I understood this great solution doesn't trust all the certificates and corresponds to the 4th solution in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https/6378872#6378872
Am I right?

Comment: @John This solution doesn't use a fall back `KeyStore`, but you can adapt your `SSLSocketFactory` to support this feature. The soluton above uses a custom `X509TrustManager` which decides whether the application is allowed to addressed a specific server, based on the public key of the certificate. The custom implementation of `checkServerTrusted` which controlls this behavour is commented out since it may not be useful for other environments.

Comment: @My-Name-Is because I am new on this could you please show me how to do that? I tried a lot based on the solution that I posted in my previous answer but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi how do you add paramaters if using httppost?

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes Please have a look at: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/ApacheHttpClient/article.html and make the adaptions within `DataLoader` class.

Comment: Do I need any certificate for this ? I coped all your code but seems like I'm missing something because I/m still facing same error : ` javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)`

Comment: @SweetWisher No, you don't have to keep the servers certificate stored on the mobile device as long you don't want to verify it, like it's done in the `checkServerTrusted` method. The verification part is commented out, so this check is just optional.

Comment: I get an error: "**SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate**"!

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky, your error message occurs for a variety of errors. Without further details it's guessing where the real problem lies.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using "Not Trusted"(developer) certificate, then below is the solution.  We need  trust all certificates, and below is the way to do that. For trusted certificates it works without adding below functionality,  we just we need to change http to https and it will work.

Here is the solution for not trusted certificate.

In HttpClient way, you should create a custom class from org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory, not the one org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory itself

example is like ...

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);

        TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };

        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }
}
```

and use this class while creating instance of HttpClient.

```
public HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
    try {
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);

        SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

        ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

        return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
}
```

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky did u solve the exception? I am getting the same.

Answer (score 7):

Check your device's date. You may have changed it to a different year. I constantly get this problem when kids use my phone.

Comment: +1 This seems to be the most common case when you get error `Νο peer certificate`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the server with a trusted certificate a much better solutionis to correctly configure the SSL because android is more restricted that iOS and desktop browser regarding SSL verification

This solution does not require any changes in your android app, so it is more clean.

Here is an example SSL configuration for apache (add it to your VirtualHost definition e.g. /etc/apache2/sites-enabled)

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile    YOUR_CERT_PATH
SSLCACertificateFile  CA_ROOT_CERT_PATH
SSLCertificateKeyFile KEY_PATH
```

I had the same error and when I added the CA root certificate, the error gone and android did not complain anymore. Provide the correct paths for these files, restart Apache and test again.

The file for the CA root certificate can contain both the root and intermediate certificate

You can test your SSL configuration with [this site](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and make sure that in the result under *Certification Paths* that the server is sending all the required certificates.

Answer (score 1):

Allow Android's security Provider to update when starting your app.

The default Provider before 5.0+ does not disable SSLv3. Provided you have access to Google Play services it is relatively straightforward to patch Android's security Provider from your app.

```
  private void updateAndroidSecurityProvider(Activity callingActivity) {
    try {
        ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(this);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
      // Thrown when Google Play Services is not installed, up-to-date, or  enabled
        // Show dialog to allow users to install, update, or otherwise    enable Google Play services.
       GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(e.getConnectionStatusCode(), callingActivity, 0);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        Log.e("SecurityException", "Google Play Services not available.");
    }
}
```

Source:
[Patching the Security Provider with ProviderInstaller Provider](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider.html?hl=zh-cn#patching)

Comment: What do you mean by `installIfNeeded(this)`?  What is **this**?

Comment: @nani well done.  Thank you for sharing this with the community.  It's unlikely I would've figured this out in a timely manner.

Answer (score 0):

When searching for this exception, all you get is the advice to implement "allow all certs".

The javadoc for SSLPeerUnverifiedException states:

> When the peer was not able to identify itself (for example; no certificate, the particular cipher suite being used does not support authentication, or no peer authentication was established during SSL handshaking) this exception is thrown.

So the error might be that the connection is so flaky/unstable and requests take ridiculous amounts of time. In our mobile app we sometimes experience lot's of connection/Socket-Timeouts in combination with these SSLPeerUnverifiedException. Some requests get through but take 60s+ - the network connection simply sucks beyond all means in these cases.

Simply brute forcing this with the "allow all certs" is not advisable in such cases - rather implement a proper retry strategy.

Comment: Socket timeouts have nothing to do with `SSLPeerUnverifiedException`. You get one or you get the other.

Comment: I'm not saying you get both at the same time. I'm not going to verify this, but back then my experience was that when dealing with very flaky connections you might get an `SSLPeerUnverifiedException` when Peer-Auth during SSL-Handshaking was interrupted. In that case you should of course end up rather with a `SSLHandshakeException`, but I'm not 100% certain you won't ever see a SSLPeerUnverifiedException "false-positive". Are you @user207421 ?

Answer (score -2):

I was originally using `HttpsURLConnection` but it wasn't working consistently so I decided to go with `HttpClient`. It works now.