# How do I find out whether a servers certificate is of type x.509 (standard)

Tags: types, certificate, pgp, verify, x509

Is there any tool available that verifies whether it's a PGP, x.509, etc. certificate? I know that I can view the details of installed certificates via the web browser (IE, FireFox, ...) and the Mircrosoft Management Console (MMC), but does a certificate version of V3 indicates that it's a x.509 type. (The latest version of x.509 is version 3)

Comment: PGP keys are not certificates and they are not available via MMC or web browser settings. Also they are almost never used in SSL/TLS. So whatever you usually see is an X.509 certificate. Now, version 3 is one of versions of X.509 certificate, and vast majority of X.509 certificates are of version 3. So your question doesn't make much sense - in 99,(9) % of cases you will deal only with X.509 certificates.

Comment: I see, it's really seldom that another certificate than x.509 is used as a server certificate. But in case of, how can I find out the type?

Comment: Load it with some code which loads only X.509 certificates and handle the error.

Comment: Is it likely that with an android https client an error: `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer` occurs?

Comment: There exist plenty of other reasons for such errors. And the wrong certificate type is the *last* of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to ***Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS Corp*** suggestion, an implementation of a `X509TrustManager` can do the job. You will find such an implementation within this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16719959/android-ssl-httpget-no-peer-certificate-error-or-connection-closed-by-peer-e/16759793#16759793).