# How to make HTTPS Post request from android to different port (not 443)?

Tags: android, ssl, http-post

Here is how I try to make HTTPS Post request in android

```
String server ="https://myserver.com:4343/api";
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(server);

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("property", value));
request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));

client.execute(request);
```

Now I have an error "No peer certificate", though certificate is correct and I can access server from browser with `GET` request.

I've tried different ways of doing POST request, tried to not specify schema or port in server string. No luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it may helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16719959/android-ssl-httpget-no-peer-certificate-error-or-connection-closed-by-peer-e

Comment: @javaseeker That answer implies that I have certificate on client, but I'm not.